# Column with list values, eliminate spaces as they are counted when performing str.len()

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a column where values are lists of strings, i.e.

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Food': [[''], ['potato', 'carrot'], ['potato', '']]})
```

that looks like:

```
Food                     
['']                       
['potato', 'carrot']      
['potato', '']
```

When I perform df['Count'] = df['Food'].str.len(), I get:

```
Food                     Count
['']                       1
['potato', 'carrot']       2  
['potato', '']             2
```

However, I want to get:

```
Food                     Count
['']                       0
['potato', 'carrot']       2  
['potato', '']             1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the number of non empty strings:

```
df['Food'].apply(lambda lst: len([e for e in lst if e != '']))
```

Comment: `df['Food'].apply(lambda lst: len([e for e in lst if e]))` also works, since `''` is treated as empty by python

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @sammywemmy. I will let it like this at the moment, as I think the OP might prefer clarity over brevity

Comment: This answer with @sammywemmy input was the most helpful and most elegant solution for my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can explode the column, sum the lengths greater than 0 (`''` has length 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Food': [[''], ['potato', 'carrot'], ['potato', '']]})
df['length'] = df['Food'].explode().str.len().gt(0).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Another possible solution is to use list comprehension (this is probably more efficient):

```
df['length'] = [len([x for x in lst if x!='']) for lst in df['Food']]
```

Output:

```
               Food  length
0                []      0
1  [potato, carrot]      2
2        [potato, ]      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` difference to exclude whichever values you don't want to count:

```
df['Count'] = df['Food'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x).difference({''})))
```

Output:

```
               Food  Count
0                []      0
1  [potato, carrot]      2
2        [potato, ]      1
```